# Why is my sql query much slower if I select a varchar field rather than a numeric one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query that is rather big (joining 3 huge tables) and running too slow. I'm trying to optimize it and ran in a strange observation :

```
SELECT board FROM ((foo JOIN bar ON id_bar=bar.id) JOIN baz ON id_baz=baz.id) ORDER BY foo.id DESC LIMIT 1;

+-------+
| board |
+-------+
|     3 |
+-------+
1 row in set (3,99 sec)
```

`board` is an int field, there is an index on it. Good. But, now, if I'm selecting an indexed `varchar(6)` field, I get that slow result :

```
SELECT type FROM ((foo JOIN bar ON id_bar=bar.id) JOIN baz ON id_baz=baz.id) ORDER BY foo.id DESC LIMIT 1;

+--------+
|  type  |
+--------+
| normal |
+--------+
1 row in set (17,76 sec)
```

How is that possible ? I thought the slow part in a query was in the `JOIN` / `ORDER` / `GROUP` / `WHERE` parts, not in the actual displaying of results. How can I enhance that query ?

Comment: At this magnitude, I would assume [board] is part of an index, while [type] is not. Or something to that effect. It's just a wild guess, though.

Comment: You seem to be hitting a a memory limitation (see answer and comment from @Mchl and @grahamj42). In order to check if this is indeed the case, put a where condition on the id field to reduce the number or records retrieved to a small number. I also want to add that indexes are totally irrelevant on the fields board and type. You can check this by using the EXPLAIN command.

Comment: @koriander `EXPLAIN` seems to indicate that one of the subqueries is `Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort` for both queries.

Comment: @koriander, you're right, putting a `where` changed the explanation to `Using where` and the result was mostly instantaneous in both cases. Hmmmm...

Comment: Looking at the joins, I just noticed it's not the typical join criteria. Given the table names you are using I assume these are not the real queries. But if your real query is doing id_bar=bar.id and id_baz=baz.id, and then order by and limit 1, then this looks broken since id_baz must be equal to id_bar and a single row is always returned (no need for for ORDER BY neither LIMIT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INT is 4 bytes long, VARCHAR(6) can be as much as 12 bytes long (in multibyte encoding). That increases the size of index, and thus increases the time.

One thing you could think about is to change `type` column into another datatype, namely `ENUM`. `ENUM` fields let you store efficiently a value from a limited set of possible values (and `type` columns often have limited amount of possible values). Because it uses less space to store data, the indices on these columns are also small, and thus faster.

Comment: To expand on this, because the query has ORDER BY, all the rows might have to be retrieved before the top record can be returned (depending on the indexes available), so the size of any temporary table will reflect the size of the field. Have you EXPLAINed the queries ?

Comment: @grahamj42, yes, I explained the queries, they both return exactly the same "explanation".

Comment: So, per your comment above, filesort is being used, which will perform worse with a bigger file and a key which is bigger than 32 bits in singlebyte encoding. If you really want a single result, you could use a subquery to select MAX(foo.id) and avoid projecting and sorting all the rows.

Comment: @grahamj42 thanks for the advice about `MAX`, that might help.

Comment: @Mchl, Just a clarification, this query does not "increases the size of index". It's the temporary table used to put together the data that increases in size.

Comment: @koriander: yeah, the query itself does not affect the size of index. My point was that index created on VARCAHR(6) column will probably be larger, and thus slower. Your explanation makes more sense though.